# How to disable selection of parts in textView?

Tags: swift, textview, selection, bullet

Imagine I have text with bullets.

- List item 1
- List item 2
- List item 3

How can I disable selection of the bullets? To select only the text:

- List item 1
- List item 2
- **List item 3**

Or event to be able to select 2 paragraphs, but without their bullets? (Like Notes app). 
Right now bullets are like normal characters in the textView and when you select the text, they are selected as well as the whitespace before them.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code to get similar results. It allows you modify the copied texted before it is added the `UIPasteboard`.

```
extension UITextView {
    override open func copy(_ sender: Any?) {
        let gpBoard = UIPasteboard.general
        let textNew: String!
        textNew = self.text
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{2022}", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range:nil)
        gpBoard.string = textNew
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but my problem is not the copy. My problem is when I am selecting text.  I start selecting text and while I am moving through the text, it select all(blue selection), I want to select only the text, without the bullets. You can Open Notes and try there

Comment: This was my solution as I could not get `textContainer.exclusionPaths` to work correctly and I believe that is how they are achieving it.  I could never get the bullet points to line up correctly.